# Save input text while switching between <option> tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a text input, alongside I have option tag with two options.
Basically I want to save the text that the user enters while switching between options, but if the user choose an option that he already enterd a text the text should appear in the input field as the default value.
And of course it's part of the submit form.

Many thanks in advance!

```
<div>
  <p>please enter your description for each of the languages</p>
  <input id="description" type="text">
  <select id="language-select">
    <option value="EN">EN</option>
    <option value="FR">FR</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: AJAX is the answer. Write a small script in the server to saveif the option is not in the db before, if exist return the text from db. You basically send the option to the AJAX method when an onchange event occur.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use local storage for this if you want to persist what is saved, otherwise a variable would be good enough.

Example with variable

```js
var previous;
var state = {};
$("#language").on('focus', function() {
  previous = $(this).val()
}).change(function() {
  state[previous] = $("#test").val();
  $("#test").val('');
  if (typeof(state[$(this).val()]) != 'undefined') {
    $("#test").val(state[$(this).val()]);
  }
  $("#test").focus();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input name="test" id="test" />
  <select id="language">
    <option val="en">EN</option>
    <option val="fr">FR</option>
  </select>
</form>
```